# Fiware-orion Remove all entities of the same type

Tags: python, fiware-orion

I dont know what command pass to the Fiware Orion API(v2) to remove all element of an specific type. In this example *fake*.

I tried this, but it doesn't works :

```
response = self.PM.request(
        method='post', url='http://127.0.0.1:1026/v2/op/update', headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body=json.dumps({
            "actionType": "delete",
            "entities": [{
                "idPattern": ".*",
                "type": "Fake",
            }]
        }))
```

I can remove the elements by ID. It is only a work around, but tells me that I am connecting correctly to the API. This is the code that works:

```
response = self.PM.request(
        method='post', url='http://127.0.0.1:1026/v2/op/update', headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body=json.dumps({
            "actionType": "delete",
            "entities": [{
                    "id": "Fake1",
                },
                {
                    "id": "Fake2",
                }
            ]}))
```

Comment: you are right, the answer I provided (now deleted) was wrong. It seems this is just not possible, at least from reading the docs

Comment: Thanks. That I suspect but I read some gits commits that hints that maybe there is a way.

Comment: where are these commits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According [to the docs](http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/1.4.1/user/delete_entity/index.html) this feature does not exist. Also, if you [search the source code for "delete type"](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=delete+type&type=) I don't see anything that matches. You'd need to do a select first and iterate through all the ids deleting them.

Comment: As side information, there is a couple of issue at Orion's repo about this: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/1645 and https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/1503. It is a pending feature.

Answer (score 0):

You are using some client in python to acess Orion Broker?

Comment: I am creating a module to access to Fiware using urllib3 library thorough its REST API.

Comment: See the method remove_entities(entity_type) in
https://github.com/juliozinga/fiot-client-python/blob/develop/fiotclient/context.py

Removes all entities with the given entity_type (Remove the first 1000 entities)